# Updating a linked table with Sequelize and Express

Tags: sql, express, sequelize.js

There are users and roles tables, which are linked in user_roles. A user can have many roles. At the time of creation, I use setRoles (array) to populate the associated user_roles table.

```
User.create(user_data)
    .then(user => {
        user.setRoles([1]).then(() => {
            console.log( "OK" );
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log( err.message );
    });
```

The question arises when updating the user, because there is no return instance of `user` to apply `setRoles(array)` to it. How can I add the following code to resolve this issue? So far, I see only one solution, to make a separate request to get an instance of the user.

PS: the Sequelize documentation says that `.update` can return an object as a second parameter, but it only works with postgres and is therefore not suitable.

```
User.update(user_data, { where: { id: user_id } })
    .then(num => {
        console.log( "OK" );
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log( err.message );
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a static model `update` method it means you can update several records (let's imagine 100000 records) and it would be a very surprising, resource and time consuming operation to get all updated records as a result of operation.

You should get an instance of a user model as you assumed in the question above and call its `update` and `setRoles` methods.